# Simultaneously running separate programs using the same token

Tags: discord, discord-jda

I have written a Discord bot using JDA (Java-Discord-API), which is added to one of my servers.

I know that the bot is using OAuth to make sure the source of the commands (in this case my Java code with the right login token) is authorized.

But I can still run a second program, which uses the same OAuth token, at the same time as the first one.

So my question is: Is possible to run multiple separate programs on multiple different machines, with different code, using the same token to operate one bot?

For example, having multiple programs, every one of those with a different bot-command programmed into it, which will then result in the right program reacting, when a certain command prefix is used in front of a command – `$test` : Program 1 reacts, `#test` : program 2 reacts, `.test` : program 3 reacts, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this. Discord doesn't mind you running multiple instances on different machines using the same token. All events will get forwarded to all your bots (as appropriately) through the websocket protocol.

It's possible to partition your bots with different prefixes using this method. But I wouldn't recommend it since all your bot scripts will have to bear the resource cost of running the bot. You will be spending multiples of RAM and CPU resource as opposed to running a single bot and handling different prefixes internally.

However, this is the recommended method when your bot grows into hundreds of thousands of servers. Through the process known as "sharding", you can split your bot in different servers into "shards" (usually 1-2k per shard) and run different shard(s) on different machines to offload the impact on one specific host server.

Note, Discord API limits you to a maximum of 1000 token logins per 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the information! How can i actually use different tokens without having to use multiple instances though?

My bot is running on 5-10 servers and will most probably stay on that level. So sharding won't be a thing with that bot.

Comment: Hello, the opposite isn't true. Unless with some heavy patching, each instance of the bot script is limited to only one token. You'll need to run multiple instances for each of your bot tokens.